# Rehosted workflows in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working in a project like this : http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx

Is it possible to upload this app in a sharepoint and executed it in sharepoint??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to  create  a separate Webservice Application (with the WF) in .net 4 and then from SharePoint you call the webservice. 
 From WF you can in turn integrate with Sharepoint through the Managed client object model. 
Refer to this link for more information on the client model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx

Comment: Finally I call in a button a javascript function to execute a exe file in sharepoint! Thanks for all joseph!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SharePoint is still using the WF3 runtime and not the WF4 runtime. So no this won't work.